# jQuery UI Draggable only work after ajax call

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have very easy problem with jQuery draggable UI. I typed a function its name is inid_drag and when i after ajax call its working good. but when type before ajax call it's not working.

Follow codes for draggable:

```
function init_drag(){

    $("#lessonTeacher li").draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });
}
```

Follow codes are working correctly:

```
        $("#classID").change(function(){
                var classID = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data:"classID=" + classID,
                url: "views/timeTablesAjax.php",

                success:function(data){

                    $("#lessonTeacher").html("");

                    $("#timeTable").hide();
                    $("#timeTable").show("slow");

                    $("#timeTable td").not(".notDrop").html("");

                    $.each(data,function(i,persons){

                        $("#lessonTeacher").append("<b>" + persons[0].code + "</b><br/>");
                        for(var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++){

                            $("#lessonTeacher").append("<li class='token-input-token-facebook' style='list-style-type: none;'>" +
                                "<p style='padding-left: 10%;' data-id=" + persons[i].ID + ">" + persons[i].staff + "</p>" +
                                "<span class='infoBox' style='background-color: #808080;'><img src='BT/upload/info.ico' width=10 height=10></span></li><br/><br/>");
                        }
                    });
                    // in this function has got draggable codes.
                    init_drag();
                }
            });
        });
```

Follow codes are not working:

```
        $("#classID").change(function(){
                var classID = $(this).val();
                    // in this function has got draggable codes.
                    init_drag();

            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data:"classID=" + classID,
                url: "views/timeTablesAjax.php",

                success:function(data){

                    $("#lessonTeacher").html("");

                    $("#timeTable").hide();
                    $("#timeTable").show("slow");

                    $("#timeTable td").not(".notDrop").html("");

                    $.each(data,function(i,persons){

                        $("#lessonTeacher").append("<b>" + persons[0].code + "</b><br/>");
                        for(var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++){

                            $("#lessonTeacher").append("<li class='token-input-token-facebook' style='list-style-type: none;'>" +
                                "<p style='padding-left: 10%;' data-id=" + persons[i].ID + ">" + persons[i].staff + "</p>" +
                                "<span class='infoBox' style='background-color: #808080;'><img src='BT/upload/info.ico' width=10 height=10></span></li><br/><br/>");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: try                     init_drag();
method in success..block

Comment: yes that's work but why not working before ajax call? i want to learn this.

Answer (score 1):

when you call         `$("#classID").change(function(){}`
it execute

```
init_drag();
```

and ajax method 
same time but in responce ajax take more time then your init_drag() method
so when you got reply with ajax the html or dragging function overlapping ur html because you append html.

Comment: After in success each loop codes are working correctly but doesn't work before this each loop. Because does not create elements(does not exist) for draggable. So how to fixed this problem for handling any time draggable there elements. If created or not created.

Comment: Solved my problem with this codes: 
                                          $(item).appendTo("#lessonTeacher").draggable({helper: 'clone'});

item is newly appended item. methinks only with this way solves there event problems.

Comment: yes you should intilize  '$(item).appendTo("#lessonTeacher").draggable({helper: 'clone'})' after creating html